# Arduino Mega: void serialEvent3() { } is not always triggering (or is it?)

Tags: serial-port, arduino

Consider:

```cpp
String cmdData; // Store the complete command on one line to send to sensor board.

String phResponse; // Store the pH sensor response.

boolean startOfLine = false;
boolean endOfLine = false;
boolean stringComplete = false;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(38400);
  Serial3.begin(38400);

  pinMode(2, OUTPUT); // Used for temperature probe
}

void loop()
{
  if (stringComplete)
  {
    Serial.println("Stored Response: " + phResponse);

    phResponse = ""; // Empty phResponse variable to get
                     // ready for the next response

    stringComplete = false;
  }
}

void serialEvent()
{
  while (Serial.available())
  {
    char cmd = (char)Serial.read();

    if (cmd == '{')
    {
      startOfLine = true;
    }

    if (cmd == '}')
    {
      endOfLine = true;
    }

    if (startOfLine && cmd != '{' && cmd != '}')
    {
      cmdData += cmd;
    }

    if (startOfLine && endOfLine)
    {
      startOfLine = false;
      endOfLine = false;

      cmdData.toLowerCase(); // Convert cmdData value to lowercase
                             // for sanity reasons

      if (cmdData == "ph")
      {
        delay(500);

        ph();
      }

      if (cmdData == "phatc")
      {
        delay(500);

        phATC();
      }

      cmdData = ""; // Empty cmdData variable to get ready for the next command
    }
  }
}

void serialEvent3()
{
  while(Serial3.available())
  {
    char cmd3 = (char)Serial3.read();

    phResponse += String(cmd3);

    if (cmd3 == '\r')
    {
      stringComplete = true;
      Serial.println("Carriage Command Found!");
    }
  }
}

float getTemp(char tempType)
{
  float v_out;           // Voltage output from temperature sensor
  float temp;            // The final temperature is stored here (this is only for code clarity)
  float tempInCelcius;   // Stores temperature in °C
  float tempInFarenheit; // Stores temperature in °F

  digitalWrite(A0, LOW); // Set pull-up resistor on analog pin
  digitalWrite(2, HIGH); // Set pin 2 high, this will turn on temperature sensor
  delay(2);              // Wait 1 ms for temperature to stabilize

  v_out = analogRead(0); // Read the input pin

  digitalWrite(2, LOW); // Set pin 2 low, this will turn off temperature sensor

  v_out *=. 0048;    // Convert ADC points to voltage [volts] (we are using .0048
                     // because this device is running at 5 volts)
  v_out *= 1000;     // Convert unit from volts to millivolts

  tempInCelcius = 0.0512 * v_out -20.5128;             // The equation from millivolts to temperature
  tempInFarenheit = (tempInCelcius * 9.0)/ 5.0 + 32.0; // Convert Celcius to Fahrenheit

  if (tempType == 'c')
  {
    return tempInCelcius; // Return temperature in Celsius
  }
  else if (tempType == 'f')
  {
    return tempInFarenheit; // Return temperature in Fahrenheit
  }
}

void ph()
{
  Serial.println("Calculating pH sensor value in 3 seconds");

  delay(3000);

  Serial3.print("r\r");
}

void phATC()
{
  Serial.println("pH auto temperature calibration will start in 3 seconds");
  delay(3000);

  float temp = getTemp('c');
  char tempAr[10];
  String tempAsString;
  String tempData;

  dtostrf(temp, 1, 2, tempAr);
  tempAsString = String(tempAr);

  tempData = tempAsString + '\r';
  Serial3.print(tempData);
}
```

Why does serialEvent3() trigger after the second and sometimes the third time a command is sent to the sensor board?  Once serialEvent3() finally triggers the consecutive commands work fluently. serialEvent() seems to work as expected.  I have tried rearranging the functions without success.  Is there a 'fail safe' time-out code to send the command again if serialEvent3 is not triggered?

Working code:

```cpp
String cmdData; // Store the complete command on one line to send to sensor board.

String phResponse; // Store the pH sensor response.

boolean startOfLine = false;
boolean endOfLine = false;
boolean stringComplete = false;

boolean s3Trigger = false;

void setup()
{
  Serial3.begin(38400);

  Serial.begin(38400);
}

void serialEvent()
{
  while (Serial.available())
  {
    char cmd = (char)Serial.read();

    if (cmd == '{')
    {
      startOfLine = true;
    }

    if (cmd == '}')
    {
      endOfLine = true;
    }

    if (startOfLine && cmd != '{' && cmd != '}')
    {
      cmdData += cmd;
      //Serial.println(cmdData);
    }
  }
}

void serialEvent3()
{
  while(Serial3.available())
  {
    char cmd3 = (char)Serial3.read();

    phResponse += String(cmd3);

    if (cmd3 == '\r') // If carriage return has been found then...
    {
      stringComplete = true;
    }
  }
}

void loop()
{
  if (startOfLine && endOfLine) // Both startOfLine and endOfLine must
                                // be true to run the command...
  {
    startOfLine = false;
    endOfLine = false;

    s3Trigger = true; // Set the s3Trigger boolean to true to check
                      // if data on Serial3.available() is available.

    runCommand();
  }

  if (stringComplete)
  {
    Serial.println("Stored Response: " + phResponse); // Print stored response from the pH sensor.

    phResponse = ""; // Empty phResponse variable to get ready for the next response
    cmdData = ""; // Empty phResponse variable to get ready for the next command

    stringComplete = false; // Set stringComplete to false
    s3Trigger = false; // Set s3Trigger to false so it doesn't continuously loop.
  }

  if (s3Trigger) // If true then continue
  {
    delay(1000); // Delay to make sure the Serial3 buffer has all the data

    if (!Serial3.available()) // If Serial3 available then execute
                              // the runCommand() function
    {
      //Serial.println("!Serial3.available()");
      runCommand();
    }
    else
    {
      s3Trigger = false; // Set s3Trigger to false so it doesn't continuously loop.
    }
  }
}

void runCommand()
{
  cmdData.toLowerCase(); // Convert cmdData value to lowercase
                         // for sanity reasons

  if (cmdData == "ph")
  {
    ph();
  }
}

void ph()
{
  Serial.println("Calculating pH sensor value in 3 seconds");

  delay(3000);

  Serial3.print("r\r");
}
```

**New working code without having to send the command twice:**

```cpp
/*
  This software was made to demonstrate how to quickly get your
  Atlas Scientific product running on the Arduino platform.
  An Arduino MEGA 2560 board was used to test this code.
  This code was written in the Arudino 1.0 IDE
  Modify the code to fit your system.
  **Type in a command in the serial monitor and the Atlas
  Scientific product will respond.**

  **The data from the Atlas Scientific product will come out
  on the serial monitor.**
  Code efficacy was NOT considered, this is a demo only.
  The TX3 line goes to the RX pin of your product.
  The RX3 line goes to the TX pin of your product.
  Make sure you also connect to power and GND pins to power
  and a common ground.
  Open TOOLS > serial monitor, set the serial monitor
  to the correct serial port and set the baud rate to 38400.
  Remember, select carriage return from the drop down menu
  next to the baud rate selection; not "both NL & CR".
*/

String inputstring = "";               // A string to hold incoming data from the PC
String sensorstring = "";              // A string to hold the data
                                       // from the Atlas Scientific product
boolean input_stringcomplete = false;  // Have we received all
                                       // the data from the PC
boolean sensor_stringcomplete = false; // Have we received all the data from
                                       // the Atlas Scientific product

#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(10, 11); // RX, TX

void setup() {    // Set up the hardware
   // Set up the hardware
   Serial.begin(38400);      // Set baud rate for the hardware
                             // serial port_0 to 38400
   mySerial.begin(38400);

   inputstring.reserve(5);   // Set aside some bytes for
                             // receiving data from the PC
   sensorstring.reserve(30); // Set aside some bytes for receiving
                             // data from Atlas Scientific product

   pinMode(12, OUTPUT);

   digitalWrite(12, HIGH);   // Turn on pull-up resistors

   //mySerial.print("i\r");
}

void serialEvent() {                   // If the hardware serial port_0 receives a char
    char inchar = (char)Serial.read(); // Get the char we just received
    inputstring += inchar;             // Add it to the inputString

    if(inchar == '\r') { // If the incoming character is a <CR>, set the flag
        input_stringcomplete = true;
    }
}


void loop() {   // Here we go....

    while(mySerial.available())
    {
        char inchar = (char)mySerial.read(); // Get the char we just received
        sensorstring += inchar;              // Add it to the inputString
        if(inchar == '\r') { // If the incoming character
                             // is a <CR>, set the flag
            sensor_stringcomplete = true;
        }

        //Serial.print(inchar);
    }

    if (input_stringcomplete){    // If a string from the PC has been
                                  // received in its entirety
        //Serial.print(inputstring);
        mySerial.print(inputstring);  // Send that string to the Atlas Scientific product
        inputstring = "";             // Clear the string:
        input_stringcomplete = false; // Reset the flag used to tell if we have
                                      // received a completed string from the PC
    }

    if (sensor_stringcomplete) {       // If a string from the Atlas Scientific
                                       // product has been received in its entirety
        Serial.println(sensorstring);  // Send that string to to the PC's serial monitor
        sensorstring = "";             // Clear the string:
        sensor_stringcomplete = false; // Reset the flag used to tell if
                                       // we have received a completed string
                                       // from the Atlas Scientific product
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing I noticed (not the cause of the serial read problem).  In a microprocessor, floating point math is expensive.  It might be worth your while to combine these three lines:

```
v_out*=.0048;
v_out*=1000;
tempInCelcius = 0.0512 * v_out -20.5128;
```

into:

```
tempInCelcius = v_out * 0.24576 -20.2128;
```

I would also move `tempInFarenheit = (tempInCelcius * 9.0)/ 5.0 + 32.0;` right into the return statement so the calculation is only done if required.  Generally splitting these lines up is encouraged for programming on a PC, but with a microprocessor I tend to compact my code and insert lots of comments.

I had a look at the example code for the sensor and I think I have something you can try.  You have a `while (Serial.available())` line in here.  I can't be certain, but this doesn't look right to me and it might be messing you up.  Try removing that block and just doing the read in the event.

Comment: I added: delay(5000); while(!Serial3.available()) { Serial.println(Serial3.read()); } to the if (cmdData == "ph").  I now receive -1 as the print out.  That is strange behavior because when the ph() function is triggered the lights blink on the sensor board.  They only blink when the sensor board receives a command or sends a response; they do blink twice for receiving and sending serial data.  I still do not understand why the second time I send {ph} a second and third time I get a response.  Link to the datasheet: http://www.atlas-scientific.com/_files/pH_Circuit_3.0.pdf

Comment: I went back to the manufacturer's example code to see if I am having the same issue and I am.  Seems like Serial3.available is not getting the first response even if I use a delay.

Comment: After looking at the datasheets I have edited my answer.  Try that and let me know.

Comment: Thank you again.  I tried your recommendation for the while() and it is still only working on the second, third, etc... time.  I resorted to moving away from the manufacturers code back to my original idea.  I added another Boolean called s3Trigger and an if statement.  Both of those implementations seemed to do the trick.  The purpose of the code amendment is to run the command again if serial3 buffer equals to -1. I edited my original post.

Comment: I stepped away from coding for a while then came back with a clear mind.  Instead of ripping apart the code I decided to take a closer look at the hardware.  After debugging the hardware for a while I started to notice that the 5v pin on the arduino mega 2560 while resetting triggered the sensor to, what I think, go into error mode.  Once in error mode I would have to send it a command to set the sensor back to normal.  Hence having to send the command twice to get the read out.  I moved the wire from 5 volts to pin 12 and set it to output and HIGH.  Everything now seems to work correctly.

Comment: For simplicity sake I went back the manufactures code and used SoftwareSerial.  I edited my original post.